# Change theme component for iOS

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I would like to create change theme component for my reader app. When user is changing theme then text and background are changing theirs colors. I was looking on other apps and I noticed that they are all using the same themes: white, back and sepia. Please refer to screenshoots below:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

It almost looks like they are all using the same mechanism. I'm wondering how I can achieve similar effect? Is there any out-of-box component what iOS provides or I need to use UIAppearance protocol or maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a singleton to manage each color, when enter the app, if there's no setting color, give the default color.

when user change the theme, u should save the color config to local data. and post the notification to tell controllers to change theme(or in viewWillAppear manual change the color).

next time you enter the app, the color manage singleton read the local config you set, and show the right theme